# python regex string split

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Have data in this way

```
data1 = 'Seattle, WA 98108'
data2 = 'SeattleWA 98108'
data3 = 'Seattle, WA98108'
data3 = 'Seattle, WA   98108'
```

how to split all cases to get data as:

```
city = 'Seattle'
state = 'WA'
zip = '98108'
```

Of course there is a lot of different cities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.findall`

```
re.findall(r'^[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+|\d+', s)
```

Example:

```
>>> def split_c(s):
    return re.findall(r'^[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+|\d+', s)

>>> split_c('Seattle, WA 98108')
['Seattle', 'WA', '98108']
>>> split_c('SeattleWA 98108')
['Seattle', 'WA', '98108']
>>> split_c('Seattle, WA98108')
['Seattle', 'WA', '98108']
>>> split_c('Seattle, WA   98108')
['Seattle', 'WA', '98108']
>>> city, state, zip_ = split_c('Seattle, WA   98108')
>>> city
'Seattle'
>>> state
'WA'
>>> zip_
'98108'
>>>
```

Comment: That only matches Seattle. You need groupings.

Comment: My bad :) That's what I get for not testing first.

Comment: hm got error for data ` Winter Park, FL  32789 ` ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: try `re.findall(r'^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*|[A-Z]+|\d+', s)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you very much :)

Comment: btw what if zip is in this format 37027-5047 not sure is it mess of data or it really exist, but have it?

Comment: `re.findall(r'^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*|[A-Z]+|[-\d]+', s)`